# Fifa 14 formation issues

Tags: fifa-14

I have been playing fifa 14 for a week now i have been having many difficulties adapting to the game play so far, that being said i played fifa 12 for 2 years and played a lot of online games and was very proficient there.

Yesterday i played many games yesterday and with many formations, The AI difficulty was professional level so the problem i encountered was when i set up a formation like 4-2-3-1 and team was Real madrid i put Alonso and Modric as holding midfielders and player Ronaldo as LAM, Di maria as CAM and Bale as RAM and Benzema as striker, there were so many times i saw Modric coming on the wings and Bale going to central midfield, even when i pause and look at the formation to verify it on the display on the pause screen it happened for so many games.

Then i tried to revert to a 4-2-2-2 with 2 at top and played Ronaldo as the striker and as game progressed it seemed to be still stuck with my previous 4-2-3-1 where ronaldo was hugging the left touch line and dropped way deep to receive the ball than i originally wanted him to play.

I am not sure how to phrase this question? Has anyone experienced this glitch so far in FIFA 14 like i pointed out with the formations and players playing out of their positions?

Secondly is there an all round formation suitable to play with on FIFA -14 i predominantly used 4-2-3-1 on FIFA 12 for all teams and go to a flat 4-4-2 only when i am trailing.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you sure the formation 4-2-2-2 is saved?

Comment: it shows the tick next to 4-2-2-2? that means its the current formation right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Modric is going up front in your 4-2-3-1 formation is because Modric has Medium defensive workrate and high attacking workrate. This is also the main reason why Cavani sucks on fifa, because he has high defensive workrate, which makes him going to the back all the time.

See this website:

http://www.futhead.com/14/players/4723/edinson-cavani/

And to the right it says the workrates.

Modric:

http://www.futhead.com/14/players/4313/luka-modric/

The 4-2-2-2 that is changing to 4-2-3-1 for you should not happen. It's not a known glitch though I think you might be forgetting something.

4-3-3 is an all round formation as well. Good if you have a fast Right winger and Left winger. Also extremely usefull for crossing which is extremely overpowered.